# Pigeon-hole principle

Tags: combinatorics

Ten points are given within a square of unit size. Then there are two of them that are closer to each other than 0.48, and there are three of them that can be covered by a disk of radius 0.5.

This question was taken from an example from the book "A walk through Combinatorics". I was able to understand first part of the question's answer. However in the second part there is a possibility that all 10 points lies outside the disc of radius 0.5. So could anyone help me out understanding the second part of the problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, you say "there is a possibility that all 10 points lies outside the disc of radius 0.5". There is no *the* disc of radius 0.5. We can place a disc of radius 0.5 anywhere in the square. So the question is can you arrange points such that you never have a case of three points falling inside any one of the many 0.5 radius disks you can place inside the square.

Comment: The second part means : "No matter how we distribute $10$ points over the unit square, we will always find a disk with radius $0.5$ containing at least three of them." This claim does nothing tell about the midpoint. The midpoint of the disk can be anywhere.

Comment: The confusion seems to be between "Given any 10 points, there is a circle that covers three of them" and "There is a circle such that, given any 10 points, three of them are covered". Those are quite different statements, and the book intends the first.

Answer (score 1):

The two diagonals of the square divide it into four right triangles. By the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) at least one of them contains at least $\lceil 10/4\rceil=3$ points. The circumcircle of that right triangle has radius $1/2$. It contains the triangle and therefore also the $3$ points and we are done. Note that the same reasoning works also for $9$ points.